# New variable in a DataFrame from another One

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with several variables. One of them is like this:

```
Name1, xx. Surname1.
Name2, yy. Surname2
```

I want to create a new variable with only the xx value for each row.

```
xx
yy
```

How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the column name where `xx` and `yy` reside?

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai Thanks Mate. The name of the column is 'Name'